# Adding materials to parts of normal maps

Tags: texture-baking, normals, normal-map

I recently came across the idea of normal maps, and I've begun baking them and using them in my work. However, I can't seem to figure out how to apply different materials to different parts of the normal map [by elevation, etc]. For example, I have this model here
[image] and I want to bake its normals and apply it to a low poly mesh. Then, I want to texture it according to its normals, so that different parts have different colors [indentations, the rod, etc, are all different materials]. Is this possible with a normal map, or do I need to bake the base color map as well?